# Can't insert a function to a element on onclick event (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with this code:

```
    var xButton = document.createElement("a");
    xButton.className = "cXButton";
    xButton.href = "#";
    xButton.onclick = "closePanel()";
    xButton.innerHTML = "X";
```

While "closePanel()" is a function I already wrote. I used Firebug and found out that "onclick" attribute doesn't appear in a tag.
I saw some threads where instead of the name of the function there is it's implementation (function closePanel(){...}). This is not what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: You can try attaching an event using a listener. An example is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720141/set-onclick-event-using-script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your have two problems in your original code:

- `"closePanel()"` is a string.
- `closePanel()` attempts to (or would if it wasn't a string) call the function and assign it's output to `xButton.onclick`

It should be this instead:

```
xButton.onClick = closePanel;
```

This will assign a reference to the function `closePanel()` to `xButton.onClick`, calling `closePanel()` when the `xButton.onClick` event is triggered.

Remember you can use `this` inside the declaration of `closePanel()` to reference the clicked element.

Comment: It works, though it onClick attribute doesn't appear in Firebug.