# Why does window.location.reload need setTimeout to work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

With these following codes it works as expected, but with around about 100 ms delay.

**app.js**

```
function refresh(){
 setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},0);
}
```

**index.htlm**

```
<body onresize="refresh()">
 <!-- dispay graph -->
<body>
```

Each time when the window's size is being readjusted by user, the graph will change accordingly. Tested on multiple browsers, window.location.reload() is sufficient, but for firefox it needs to be wrapped around by setTimeout.

Read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019518/why-does-window-location-reload-need-to-be-wrapped-in-a-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720141/set-onclick-event-using-script/11720212#11720212), but still I don't understand why. Haven't I wrapped `window.location.reload` inside `refresh` function?

Also about the problem with pointing `window.location.reload` to the right `this`, wouldn't method function be enough to assign correct `this` to the window so it shouldn't need to be wrapped by other function?

Comment: Well, it's because, apparently, in Firefox, the context is not preserved. For reference, you should be able to pass `window.location.reload.bind(window.location)` instead of wrapping the call in a function...but I don't think this looks better.

Comment: Thank vlaz, could you explain little more on why do we need to do `window.location.reload.bind(window.location)`? why is `window.location.reload.bind()` is different from plain `window.location.reload`?

Comment: When you execute a function it runs within its _context_. With the `reload` function, the context is the `location` object (or, more explicitly `window.location`). The context is essentially what `this` refers to within a function - some functions may ignore it (if they don't use `this`) or if they have the context sort of "attached", so it's always correct. When using `.bind` that does the "attaching" - the function context is static and cannot be changed. Firefox apparently does not do that for the `window.location` functions, so you either have to do `.bind` or call it as `location.reload`.

Comment: Initially I was using `location.reload` and after I noticed it didn't work with firefox. I did some digging, people suggested to use `window.location.reload` because it works with multiple platforms except netscape <2.0.