# setTimeout function not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am trying to use

`<input type="submit" name="add" class="buy" onClick="setTimeout('history.go(0);',2000);"/>`

It reloads the page on click after two seconds in chrome but it doesnt work in Firefox.

I went through this [Why does window.location.reload need setTimeout to work in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250706/why-does-window-location-reload-need-settimeout-to-work-in-firefox). It still didn't work for me. Please help me find a way I can achieve my required functionality accross both browsers.

Comment: While a string of code is a [valid parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Parameters) to `setTimeout`, it is fraught with the same issues that `eval` has. Why not pass a function that calls `history.go(0)` instead?

Comment: @chazsolo I tried history.go(0) but it doesn't refresh all the fields on the page in the chrome and doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: You tried `setTimeout(function() { history.go(0); }, 2000);`? Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us understand?

Comment: @chazsolo on the page which I want to refresh on click has fields like height width counter_number which are supposed to be zero on refresh. All these field refresh when I click the button in chrome but this onclick function doesnt work in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made it work.

```
<input type="submit" name="add" class="buy" onClick="timeDelay()"/>

<script>
    function timeDelay(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload(true);
        },6000);
      }      
</script>
```